# Click the correct edit link next to certain item using Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

This is my first ever post.

I have recently started using Python and Selenium to do some administrative work on several websites. All websites have the same domain and are setup in a similar way.

After searching online for about a week now I wasn't able to find anything related to the following issue. I will try to explain the problem I'm facing:

website 1:

```
Apple   Remove  Edit Copy
Banana  Remove  Edit Copy
Pear    Remove  Edit Copy

        <tbody><tr>
            <td></td> 
            <td align="left"><span id="Items_01_ItemName">Apple</span></td> 
            <td><a id="Items_01_Remove" href="hidden">Remove</a>                
            <a id="Items_01_Edit" href="hidden">Edit</a>
            <a id="Items_01_Copy" href="hidden">Copy</a></td>
        </tr>
    
        <tr>
            <td></td> 
            <td align="left"><span id="Items_02_ItemName">Banana</span></td> 
            <td><a id="Items_02_Remove" href="hidden">Remove</a>                
            <a id="Items_02_Edit" href="hidden">Edit</a>
            <a id="Items_02_Copy" href="hidden">Copy</a></td>
        </tr>
    
        <tr>
            <td></td> 
            <td align="left"><span id="Items_03_ItemName">Pear</span></td> 
            <td><a id="Items_03_Remove" href="hidden">Remove</a>                
            <a id="Items_03_Edit" href="hidden">Edit</a>
            <a id="Items_03_Copy" href="hidden">Copy</a></td>
        </tr>
```

website 2:

```
Banana  Remove  Edit Copy
Pear    Remove  Edit Copy
Apple   Remove  Edit Copy

        <tbody><tr>
            <td></td> 
            <td align="left"><span id="Items_01_ItemName">Banana</span></td> 
            <td><a id="Items_01_Remove" href="hidden">Remove</a>                
            <a id="Items_01_Edit" href="hidden">Edit</a>
            <a id="Items_01_Copy" href="hidden">Copy</a></td>
        </tr>
    
        <tr>
            <td></td> 
            <td align="left"><span id="Items_02_ItemName">Pear</span></td> 
            <td><a id="Items_02_Remove" href="hidden">Remove</a>                
            <a id="Items_02_Edit" href="hidden">Edit</a>
            <a id="Items_02_Copy" href="hidden">Copy</a></td>
        </tr>
    
        <tr>
            <td></td> 
            <td align="left"><span id="Items_03_ItemName">Apple</span></td> 
            <td><a id="Items_03_Remove" href="hidden">Remove</a>                
            <a id="Items_03_Edit" href="hidden">Edit</a>
            <a id="Items_03_Copy" href="hidden">Copy</a></td>
        </tr>
```

How can I make selenium click the edit link for instance for the item Pear? For website 1 it is the edit link no. 3 and for website 2 it is edit link no.2

I would like my script to be able to click the edit link for the item "Pear" regardless of its position.

I hope my question is clear and someone is able to point me in the correct direction.

Thank you.

Comment: Instead of handmade HTML update the question with the text based actual HTML.

Comment: You'd most like start with //div[.='Banana']//following::div[.='Edit'] or something similar to that  without knowing the layout though I am not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the updated page source example, try:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(@id, 'ItemName')][text()='Pear']/../following::a[contains(@id, 'Edit')]")
```

Comment: This still clicks the first edit button it sees on the webpage.

The only thing connecting the item name to the edit link is: id="Items_03_ItemName" and id="Items_03_lnkEdit"

For the second website it is: id="Items_02_ItemName" and id="Items_02_lnkEdit"

Comment: It seems I first need to grab part of the <id> for the item "Pear" (Items_03) and in some way use that to click the edit button with the <id> containing "Items_03". How would I go about this?

Comment: I've updated the xpath based on your updated page source, please, try this.

Comment: This worked like a charm! So, the part of the code that says "../following::......" does the magic and finds the relative edit link? Thank you so much!

Comment: Yes, since your span was inside td, we should go one level up with `/..`, and then following will find the next ongoing node on the same level.

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining. This helps me a lot and hopefully others with similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

you can filter for name ->

if driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="DwsldCn"]/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[4]/a').get_attribute("name")=="banana":
print("perfect"